# Ezoic CSRF Token Issues

Tags: laravel, csrf, cloudflare

We recently moved our Laravel-based site to Ezoic. However, we have some problems when we activate the caches via Leap. The problems are as follows.

When cache is active

csrf tokens are the same on every computer,
Since our website is a user-login site, we get a "419" page expired error as a login error.
And finally, the latest uploaded content does not appear on the pages.
When we disable cache

The site is working properly, but the page speed is performing very poorly because the cache is not working.
What can we do about it? This problem poses a major problem for our users. How can we solve it? Is there a possibility that there is a problem with the Cloudflare dns or the dns on our host

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.